# Use product from one calculation in another - SQL select statement

Tags: sql, select

This is my lengthy SQL code. I am essentially trying to convert database info first from monthly, daily, and yearly rates to hourly. Then convert this hourly number to USD if it is not already.

So far, I have a converted UOM rate as "converted rate," but how do I use this newly converted rate when converting to USD? I.e. in:

WHEN wo.currency = 'GBP' then (wo.avg_rate*1.66)

I cannot change wo.avg_rate to either wo.converted_rate, x.converted_rate, "converted rate," or 'converted rate.' How can I do this ?

```
SELECT 
    x.work_order_ref as 'Work Order Reference'
    ,x.buyer_code as 'Buyer Code'
    ,x.submit_time as 'Work Order Submit Time'
    ,x.rate_unit_for_spend_calc as 'UOM'
    ,x.avg_rate as 'ST Rate'
    ,x.converted_rate as 'Converted Rate'
    ,x.currency as 'Currency'
    ,x.converted_amount AS 'Converted Amount'
    ,jp.title AS 'JP Title'
    ,lbt.name AS 'Labor Type'
    ,jp.max_distribution_level AS 'Max Distr Level'
    ,si.city AS 'City'
    ,si.state_province as 'State'
    ,si.country AS 'Country'
    ,ctg.name AS 'Category'
    ,count(jpd.supplier_code) as 'Suppliers'
from 
(select 
         wo.work_order_ref
         ,wo.buyer_code
         ,wo.submit_time
         ,wo.rate_unit_for_spend_calc 
         ,"converted_rate" = 
                        CASE
                        WHEN wo.rate_unit_for_spend_calc='Hr' then wo.avg_rate
                        WHEN wo.rate_unit_for_spend_calc='MO' then (wo.avg_rate/173.333)
                        WHEN wo.rate_unit_for_spend_calc='Day' then (wo.avg_rate/8)
                        WHEN wo.rate_unit_for_spend_calc='Yr' then (wo.avg_rate/2080)
                        END
         ,wo.avg_rate
         ,wo.currency
         ,wo.job_posting_id
         ,wo.site_id
         ,wo.worker_id
         ,wo.uploaded_flag
         ,wo.sequence
         ,"converted_amount" =
                        CASE
                        WHEN wo.currency='USD' then (wo.avg_rate)
                        WHEN wo.currency='GBP' then (wo.avg_rate*1.66)
                        WHEN wo.currency='SEK' then (wo.avg_rate*0.14)
                        WHEN wo.currency='EUR' then (wo.avg_rate*1.31)
                        WHEN wo.currency='CAD' then (wo.avg_rate*0.92)
                        WHEN wo.currency='AUD' then (wo.avg_rate*0.93)
                        WHEN wo.currency='INR' then (wo.avg_rate*0.017)
                        WHEN wo.currency='MXN' then (wo.avg_rate*0.076)
                        WHEN wo.currency='COP' then (wo.avg_rate*0.00052)
                        WHEN wo.currency='BRL' then (wo.avg_rate*0.44)
                        WHEN wo.currency='MYR' then (wo.avg_rate*0.32)
                        WHEN wo.currency='CNY' then (wo.avg_rate*0.16)
                        WHEN wo.currency='RON' then (wo.avg_rate*0.3)
                        WHEN wo.currency='CZK' then (wo.avg_rate*0.047)
                        WHEN wo.currency='SGD' then (wo.avg_rate*0.8)
                        WHEN wo.currency='PLN' then (wo.avg_rate*0.31)
                        WHEN wo.currency='JPY' then (wo.avg_rate*0.0096)
                        WHEN wo.currency='NZD' then (wo.avg_rate*0.84)
                        WHEN wo.currency='CHF' then (wo.avg_rate*1.09)
                        --ELSE (wo.avg_rate*x.conversion_factor)
                        END
    from work_order wo(nolock) ) as x
```

...

If it makes it better for me to post full code and/or what I'm getting, I can do that as well.

Comment: It's not clear for me what the issue is. What do you mean by "cannot change wo.avg_rate to either wo.converted_rate, x.converted_rate, "converted rate," or 'converted rate." ?

Comment: For your future sanity, put the conversion rates into a table.

Comment: Not quite sure about your idea, but it seems like bad approach. Better try with functions, it gives more flexibility. And as @Laurence said, use conversion table for exchange rates.

Answer (score 0):

If you stored the conversions in tables, it makes the query far easier. You may even be able to get rid of the inner query:

```
declare @uom table (
    unit char(3) not null primary key,
    divisor decimal(10, 5) not null
);

insert into @uom values
    ('Hr', 1), ('MO', 173.333), ('Day', 8), ('Yr', 2080);

declare @rate table (
    currency char(3) not null primary key,
    usd_mult decimal(10, 5) not null
);

insert into @rate values
    ('USD', 1), ('GBP', 1.66), ('SEK', 0.14), ('EUR', 1.31),
    ('CAD', 0.92), ('AUD', 0.93), ('INR', 0.017), ('MXN', 0.076),
    ('COP', 0.00052), ('BRL', 0.44), ('MYR', 0.32), ('CNY', 0.16),
    ('RON', 0.3), ('CZK', 0.047), ('SGD', 0.8), ('PLN', 0.31),
    ('JPY', 0.0096), ('NZD', 0.84), ('CHF', 1.09);

select 
    wo.work_order_ref,
    wo.buyer_code,
    wo.submit_time,
    wo.rate_unit_for_spend_calc,
    wo.avg_rate / u.dividend as converted_rate,
    wo.avg_rate,
    wo.currency,
    wo.job_posting_id,
    wo.site_id,
    wo.worker_id,
    wo.uploaded_flag,
    wo.sequence,
    -- is this where you wanted converted_rate * currency_mult?
    wo.avg_rate / u.dividend * r.usd_mult as converted_amount
from 
    work_order wo with (nolock)
        inner join
    @uom u
        on wo.rate_unit_for_spend_calc = u.unit
        inner join
    @rate r
        on wo.currency = r.currency
)
```

Failing this, you can hide the calculations behind functions. This makes things easier to read, but can slow the query down, as the optimizer has trouble seeing through the functions:

```
create function dbo.HourlyRate(@unit as char(3), @rate as decimal(10, 5)) returns decimal(10, 5) as
begin
    return case @unit
        when 'Hr' then @rate
        when 'MO' then @rate / 173.333
        when 'Day' then @rate / 8
        when 'Yr' then @rate / 2080
    end
end

create function dbo.ConvertToUSD(@currency as char(3), @amount as decimal(20, 5)) returns decimal(20, 5) as
begin
    return case @currency
        when 'USD' then @amount
        when 'GBP' then @amount * 1.66
        ...
    end
end
```

Call it like so:

```
select
    ...
    dbo.HourlyRate(wo.rate_unit_for_spend_calc, wo.avg_rate) as converted_rate,
    ...
    dbo.ConvertToUSD(wo.currency, dbo.HourlyRate(wo.rate_unit_for_spend_calc, wo_avg_rate) as converted_amount,
    ...
from
    work_order wo with (nolock)
```